# Specific JRE auto-download with JNLP in 64-bit Internet Explorer

Tags: java, applet, 32bit-64bit, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm trying to get a JWS applet to load properly.  My understanding is that [starting with JRE 1.6.0_12](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u12-137788.html), Java Web Start supports 64-bit auto-install.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit Enterprise.  I test in Internet Explorer 9 32-bit and 64-bit.  I want the applet to load, and if a specific version of the JRE is not found, to download and install it.

I have JRE 1.6.0_26 in both 64-bit and 32-bit installed and working prior to loading the applet.  JRE 1.7.0 is also installed.  The JNLP specifies 1.6.0_21 as the required release, so it should launch an installer and download that version.

Everything works properly in IE-32, but IE-64 fails.

When I load the page in IE-64, it starts the JWS installer applet like it's supposed to, but then I receive errors in the applet console.  An additional blank Java window appears (it's a small window with no content) and no further interaction with the open Java windows is possible.  The only way to get rid of them is to find javaw.exe in Task Manager and kill the process.

When using JRE64 1.7.0, the error in the console is (leaving out the stack trace because I can't copy it -- it's frozen):

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\x\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\
    Deployment\cache\6.0\ext\E1314222239880\j2re-installer.dll:
    Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD64-bit platform
    <stack trace>
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### null
```

When JRE64 1.7.0 is disabled, and using JRE64 1.6.0_26, the error is different (and it doesn't freeze up):

```
Could not launch from cache. Will try online mode. [Some of required resources
are not cached.]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\x\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\
    Deployment\cache\6.0\ext\E1314222239880\j2re-installer.dll:
    Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.webstart.installers.Main.install(Main.java:156)
    at com.sun.webstart.installers.Main.main(Main.java:554)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### null
```

Clicking on the Details for the JWS installer Error window provides the JNLP file the JWS installer uses:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/jawsautodl/AutoDL/j2se">
    <information>
        <title>J2RE 1.6.0_21 Installer</title>
        <vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</vendor>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.3+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="javaws-j2re-inst-w.jar" download="lazy" size="70700"/>
        <property name="installerLocation" value="jre-6u21-windows-i586-iftw.exe"/>
        <property name="installerSize"     value="874272"/>
        <property name="javaVersion"       value="1.6.0_21"/>
        <property name="platformVersion"   value="1.6"/>
        <property name="msvcrt.versionMS"  value="60000"/>
        <property name="msvcrt.versionLS"  value="20910000"/>
        <property name="osplatform"        value="windows-i586"/>
    </resources>
    <installer-desc main-class="com.sun.webstart.installers.Main"/>
</jnlp>
```

This shows it trying to download the installer for a target platform of Windows i586, not AMD64.  In the Java console that shows the stack trace, if I dump system properties I get these:

```
os.arch = amd64
os.name = Windows 7
os.version = 6.1
osplatform = windows-i586
platformVersion = 1.6
sun.arch.data.model = 64
sun.cpu.endian = little
sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
sun.desktop = windows
```

My JNLP file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="http://some_host/some_path/"
      href="http://some_host/some_path/some_applet.jnlp">
   <information>
      <title>...</title>
      <homepage href="..." />
      <description>...</description>
      <vendor>...</vendor>
   </information>
   <security>
      <all-permissions />
   </security>
   <resources>
      <java version="1.6.0_21" max-heap-size="512M" java-vm-args="-Xss=256K"/>
      <jar href="some_applet.jar" />
   </resources>
   <applet-desc
         name="some_applet"
         main-class="com.some_applet.SomeApplet"
         width="1152"
         height="864"
         >
   </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

So what gives?  Is there a way to make this work in both 32-bit and 64-bit browsers, in particular making sure 64-bit IE can download a specific 64-bit JRE?

Comment: I don't think this would cause your main problem, but I usually use the JNLP spec nomenclature of "1.x+" instead of "x.0+". Not sure if this would actually cause an issues either, however I figured I would mention it. I also realize this question is 3 years old at this point, and you've probably(?) fixed this issue (hopefully).